# using hoverData in plotly dash to create hover go.Table

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to use the hoverData of a plot with many traces to display a side table of values related to each trace. The main code runs as follows. (note this is not the full code, but i included the relevant info)

```
def plots(self,):    
        
        df_lists = self.df_lists
        plots_names = ['weakness', 'std', 'std_average', 'std_weak', 'p_average', 'p_repitition_average', 'p_median','p_median_all', 'p_median_average','p_range', 'p_range_average']
        colors = {'background': '#111111', 'text': '#7FDBFF'}
        from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
        names = self.names
        app = Dash()
        app.layout = html.Div( children=[
            html.H4('Dieharder Tests Plots'),
            html.P('Chose Plot Type'),
            dcc.RadioItems(plots_names, plots_names[0], id="plot-picker", ),
            html.P('Test Description'),
            dcc.Markdown(id='test-explain',  link_target="_blank", ),
            html.P("Filter by test:"),
            dcc.Dropdown(names, names[0], id="test-picker", multi = True), 
            dcc.Graph(id="plot",  style={'width':'75%', 'float': 'left','height': '70vh','display':'inline-block'}),
            html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='hover-data', style ={'float':'right'})], style={'width':'20%', 'paddingTop':35}),           
                     
                ])
       
        
        
        @app.callback(
            Output("plot", "figure"), 
            [Input("plot-picker", "value"), Input("test-picker", "value")])
        def update_bar_chart(plot_picker, picker_test):
            i=0
            if plot_picker == 'weakness':              
                data = []
                for test in picker_test:
                    df = df_lists[test]
                    p_value = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('pva')]
                    n_rounds = len(p_value)
                    trace = go.Bar(x=df.test_name, y = df.weak_rate, name = '{}, #rounds: {}'.format(test,n_rounds))
                    data.append(trace)
                
                layout = go.Layout(title = 'Fraction of weak and failed results per each Dieharder test')
                fig = go.Figure(data, layout)
                fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Failed/weak fractions')
                fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.99, xanchor="left", x=0.01))
                return fig
```

The hover data includes the number of the trace not its name, which i need to specify the df source of the data. I am using the following code to get the hover data to generate the table:

```
@app.callback(Output('hover-data', 'graph'),
                      [Input('plot', 'hoverData')] ) 
        def hover_data(hoverData):
   
            Die_test = hoverData['points'][0]['x']
            curve_number = hoverData['points'][0]['curveNumber']
            trace_name = app.layout['plot'].figure['data'][curve_number]['name']
            df = df_lists[trace_name]
            df = df[df['test_name'] == Die_test]
            data = [go.Table(header=dict(values=['p_mean', 'p_median', 'range', 'std'], fill_color='paleturquoise', align='left'), cells=dict(values=[df['p_mean'], df['p_median'], df['range'], df['std']] ))]

            fig = go.Figure(data,) 
            return fig
```

The problem it is not working. I am not seeing anything when i hover over the data. I am not sure where the problem is coming, but most probably from the trace_name variable as i am getting the error:

```
Callback error updating hover-data.graph
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'figure'.
```

I tried to include a [State('plot', 'figure')] in the input of the callback. and then use the .figure['data'][curve_number]['name'] directly (instead of using app.layout['plot'] first), but it also didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your dataframe so I think you can refer my code to revise yours:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

df = pd.read_csv('https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Fertility rate, total (births per woman)',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-column',
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1}),

        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Life expectancy at birth, total (years)',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-column'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1})
    ], style={'padding': '10px 5px'}, className='p-2 align-items-center'),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(
                id='crossfilter-indicator-scatter',
                hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': 'Japan'}]}
            )
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1}),
        dbc.Col([
            dash_table.DataTable(id='table',
                                 columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                                 data=[],
                                 style_table={'height': 550},
                                 style_header={'backgroundColor': 'orange', 'padding': '10px', 'color': '#000000'},
                                 style_cell={'textAlign': 'center', 'font_size': '12px',
                                             'whiteSpace': 'normal', 'height': 'auto'},
                                 editable=True,  # allow editing of data inside all cells
                                 filter_action="native",  # allow filtering of data by user ('native') or not ('none)
                                 sort_action="native",  # enables data to be sorted per-column by user or not ('none')
                                 sort_mode="single",  # sort across 'multi' or 'single' columns
                                 column_selectable="multi",  # allow users to select 'multi' or 'single' columns
                                 row_selectable="multi",  # allow users to select 'multi' or 'single' rows
                                 row_deletable=True,  # choose if user can delete a row (True) or not (False)
                                 selected_columns=[],  # ids of columns that user selects
                                 selected_rows=[],  # indices of rows that user selects
                                 page_action="native",
                                 export_headers='display')
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1}),
    ], className='p-2 align-items-center'),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Slider(
                df['Year'].min(),
                df['Year'].max(),
                step=None,
                id='crossfilter-year--slider',
                value=df['Year'].max(),
                marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
            )
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1})
    ], className='p-2 align-items-center')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value'))
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    fig = px.scatter(x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
                     y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
                     hover_name=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])

    fig.update_traces(customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])
    fig.update_xaxes(title=xaxis_column_name, type='linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')
    fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name, type='linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')
    fig.update_layout(margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')
    return fig

@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'))
def update_y_timeseries(hoverData, xaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    country_name = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]
    return dff.to_dict(orient='records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=1414)
```

I think instead of return `go.Table`, you can use dash_table in your Div and then return filtered data frame. Hope this help.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. i will implement it and check how it will work...